# No implicit int -> short conversion in ternary statement

Tags: c#, ternary-operator, implicit-conversion

```
short s;
s = (EitherTrueOrFalse()) ? 0 : 1;
```

This fails with:

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly
>   convert type 'int' to 'short'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you
>   missing a cast?)

Can anyone explain why this is so? The only thing I can think of is that the compiler doesn't look at the second value and doesn't know the range between the two, in the case I wrote something like

```
short s;
s = (EitherTrueOrFalse()) ? 0 : 65000;
```

Correct?
The only fix is with an ugly cast?

Also, it seems C# does not have a type suffix for the short type. That's a pretty grave oversight IMO. Otherwise, that would've been a solution...

Comment: You are right, there's no type suffix for the short type.

Comment: There is no type suffix for the short type, but I would hardly call it a "grave oversight". Somehow we .net developers have managed to cope with this heinous disability...

Comment: Well, for some reason VB has it...

Comment: int/short constant conversions in conditional operators actually lead to some interesting language design issues. If this subject interests you, soo https://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/24/type-inference-woes-part-one.aspx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The compiler has an implicit conversion from a *constant* expression to various primitive types (so long as the value is within the appropriate range), but here the expression isn't constant - it's just an int expression. It's pretty much the same as:

```
short s;
s = CallSomeMethodReturningInt32();
```

as far as the compiler is concerned.

There are two options - you could cast the whole expression, or cast each of the latter two operands:

```
short s = (EitherTrueOrFalse()) ? (short) 0 : (short) 1;
```

to make the overall expression type `short`. In this particular case, it's a pity that there isn't a numeric literal suffix to explicitly declare a `short` literal. Apparently the language designers did consider this, but felt it was a relatively rare situation. (I think I'd probably agree.)

The part about implicit constant conversions is from the C# 3.0 spec section 6.1.8:

> **6.1.8 Implicit constant expression conversions**
>
> An implicit constant
>   expression conversion permits the
>   following conversions:
>
> - A *constant-expression* (§7.18) of type
>     `int` can be converted to type sbyte,
>     `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `uint`, or `ulong`,
>     provided the value of the
>     *constant-expression* is within the
>     range of the destination type.
> - A
>     *constant-expression* of type `long` can
>     be converted to type `ulong`, provided
>     the value of the *constant-expression*
>     is not negative.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest to cast the whole expression, because this will be executed at runtime, while the cast of the constant is executed by the compiler.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense. And yeah, this is the first time I've come across it, so it's probably right to consider it rare or rare-ish. Still, a shame there's no suffix.

Answer (score 1):

Because the **cast is done by the compiler**, not at runtime, I wouldn't call it an ugly cast, I would call it a complicated syntax:

```
s = (EitherTrueOrFalse()) ? (short)0 : (short)1;
```

I mean, this is the way it is written in C#, even if it looks ugly.

See this [blog article](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/08/secrets-and-lies-of-type-suffixes-in-c-and-vb-net/).
See [Marc Gravell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166752/c-compiler-number-literals) on that question.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this has the same reason as this won't compile:

```
short s1 = GetShort1();
short s2 = GetShort2();
short s3 = s1 + s2;
```

I.e. that whenever short is used for something, it gets promoted to int.

Comment: No, that's not the reason. It's not "whenever short is used for something". In particular, if the 0 and 1 were actually s1 and s2, it would be fine. The reason addition fails in your case is because there's no addition operator defined for short, so the values are promoted to int.

Comment: Or, if you like, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547216/why-do-i-need-to-wrap-this-code-in-a-cast-to-short