# Why is zero chosen to be Int32 inside Ternary Operator?

Tags: c#, type-conversion, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No implicit int -> short conversion in ternary statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672774/no-implicit-int-short-conversion-in-ternary-statement)

So I understand the fundamentals of type conversion and inference of types in the C# ternary operator, thanks mostly to Eric Lippert's answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215745/conditional-operator-cannot-cast-implicitly/2215959#2215959). But the thing I'm still not understanding is what I have below.

I guess I understand that C# is assuming the zero is an `int` because that's somehow the default, so an error is thrown when I try to assign an `int` to a `short` variable:

```
short recordNumber = Convert.IsDBNull(dr["record_number"]) ? 0 
    : Convert.ToInt16(dr["record_number"]);
```

This error gets thrown:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'. 
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

This is what VS10 is looking for:

```
short recordNumber = Convert.IsDBNull(dr["record_number"]) ? (short)0 
    : Convert.ToInt16(dr["record_number"]);
```

What I'm trying to understand is **why is 0 chosen to be `int` rather than `short`?**  If it was chosen to be a `short` then that would make it more universally "assignable".  Is there some reason for this that I'm missing?

Comment: Thanks @JonB, I dug and dug and couldn't find a similar question.  But in that question, the answer (even though it's a good one from Jon Skeet) is more saying how to fix it.  I'm trying to find out why it was chosen that 0 would be `int` over `short`.  Different enough? I'm not sure...  I'll let the community decide and close if needed.

Comment: @JonB I also changed the subject as it could have been misleading and wasn't focused on the basis of my question.  I understand why it causes the error, I want to know zero is `int` and not `short`.

Comment: Take a look at Eric's blog post, linked from the comments of that question: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/05/24/type-inference-woes-part-one.aspx "Since the types are not the same, and literal zero goes to short, and s goes to int, no expression type can be determined and we report an error"