# Using C# ternary with String.Equals

Tags: c#, .net

This works:

```
short value;
value = 10 > 4 ? 5 : 10;
```

This works:

```
short value;
value = "test" == "test" ? 5 : 10;
```

This doesn't work:

```
short value;
string str = "test";
value = "test" == str ? 5 : 10;
```

Neither does this:

```
short value;
string str = "test";
value = "test".Equals(str) ? 5 : 10;
```

The last two cases I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'short'.
An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Why do I have to cast on the last two cases and not on the two first cases?

Comment: @Tyler: indeed, sorry removed the close vote. The duplicate one I gave was not specific. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678792/are-string-equals-and-operator-really-same?rq=1 States the difference between compile-time (==) and run-time (equals). Also 10 > 4 will be optimized out by the compiler where a variable is most of the time checked run-time (of not a constant)

Comment: possible duplicate of [No implicit int -> short conversion in ternary statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672774/no-implicit-int-short-conversion-in-ternary-statement)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
short value;
value = 10 > 4 ? 5 : 10;             //1
value = "test" == "test" ? 5 : 10;   //2
string str = "test";
value = "test" == str ? 5 : 10;      //3
value = "test".Equals(str) ? 5 : 10; //4
```

The last two ternary expressions (3,4) cannot be resolved to a constant at compile time. Thus the compiler treats the `5` and `10` as `int` literals, and the type of the entire ternary expression is `int`. To convert from an `int` to a `short` requires an explicit cast.

The first two ternary expressions (1,2) *can* be resolved to a constant at compile time. The constant value is an `int`, but the compiler knows it fits in a `short`, and thus does not require any casting.

For fun, try this:

```
value = "test" == "test" ? 5 : (int)short.MaxValue + 1;
```

Comment: For reference: this behavior implemented by the compiler is called [Constant Folding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding)

Comment: @Groo -- You know it took less than 10 mins for the correct answer.

Comment: [Here's the MS Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) that says this can happen. "A constant expression of type int can be converted to sbyte, byte, short, ushort, uint, or ulong, provided the value of the constant expression is within the range of the destination type." But this doesn't really explain why the compiler can't figure out that both 5 and 10 can be shorts, other than the obvious "because it can't".

Comment: @ahruss The compiler absolutely can figure out that both 5 and 10 can be `short`. The problem is, if `E` is the expression `B ? X : Y` where `B` is a non-constant `bool` expression, then `E` is always interpreted as a non-constant expression, regardless of whether `X` and `Y` are constant or not. If `X` is `5` and `Y` is `10`, the types of those expressions are both `int`. So `E` is non-constant and has type `int`. A non-constant `int` cannot be implicitly cast to a `short`.

Comment: @ahruss (continued)  The compiler reasons by constant versus non-constant - it doesn't keep bounds for non-constant variables. The reasoning you are suggesting would require the compiler to say `B ? 5 : 10` is always going to be a value in `[5, 10]`.

Comment: @TimothyShields It could just as easily look at the form of the expression and figure out the required types: (bool) ? (short) : (short). I know expressions are supposed to have types on their own, but C# is not even consistent with that. Lambdas infer their type from usage, for example. So what's the downside to figuring out the type for integer literals based on the expected type of the expression? (There's a similar problem with `null` in similar situations this could also resolve.)

Comment: @ahruss Type inference only flows up the abstract syntax tree. It's not a violation of that statement when the compiler allows `short x = <const int expression>;` or `f(<const int expression>)` where the signature is `void f(short x)` - as long as the `<const int expression>` fits in a `short`. When I write `short x = 5;`, the `5` is still an `int` literal, not a `short` literal. You could imagine a compiler that can do type inference in both directions on the abstract syntax tree - for example `if (E) { ... }` would imply that `E` should be a `bool` - but the C# compiler doesn't do that.

Comment: @TimothyShields It only flows up... except when it doesn't. It flows down for lambdas.

Comment: @ahruss No, it doesn't. Lambda expressions do not derive their type from things above them in the AST. In fact, *lambda expressions don't have a type at all* in the AST. I think this comment thread is getting too long. Might not be a bad idea to ask a standalone question about the lambda expression typing.

Answer (score 4):

You need a cast to make the two last examples work

```
value = (short)("test" == str ? 5 : 10);
```

Why dont't you need it in the first two?

Because the first two are compile-time constants. The compiler is able to translate `10 > 4 ? 5 : 10` to `true ? 5 : 10`, then to just `5`

So when you write

```
value = 10 > 4 ? 5 : 10;
```

It's effectively the same as

```
value = 5;
```

which compiles because the compiler is allowed to implicitly cast constants if they are in the allowed range.

Conversely, `"test" == str ? 5 : 10;` is not a compile time constant, so the compile is not allowed to implcitly cast it. You need to make an explicit cast yoursef.

Comment: Entirely correct. For an "academic" difference between `(short)("test" == str ? 5 : 10)` and `"test" == str ? (short)5 : (short)10`, see my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is defined by the C# Language Specification, of course.

The key thing to be aware of is that there are two kinds of conversions *from* `int` *to* `short`. One is an *explicit* conversion which always applies but which requires you to write `(short)` explicitly before the `int` expression. The other one is an ***[implicit constant expression conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691286.aspx)*** which only applies when **(a)** the `int` expression is a compile-time constant and **(b)** the value of this compile-time expression is within the range of a `short`, that is `-32768` through `32767`.

A literal like `5`, `10` or `4` has type `int` in C# (that goes for any integer literal which is between `-2147483648` and `2147483647` and not followed by a symbol `L`, `U` or similar). So if we look at the right-hand sides of all your assignments, they are clearly `int` expressions, not `short`.

In the case `10 > 4 ? 5 : 10`, since `10` and `4` are compile-time constants, this is the same as `true ? 5 : 10` because the `>` operator between `int`s is built-in and will result in a constant when the operands are constants. And in the same way `true ? 5 : 10` gives `5` because all three operands are constants, and `?:` is classified a constant itself in that case. So it really says:

```
short value = 5;
```

where the "`5`" is a compile-time constant. Hence it is checked at compile-time if the `int` `5` is within the range (it does not matter with the `10`, it could be `999999`), and since that is the case, the *implicit constant expression conversion* applies, and it is legal.

Note that you can do the same with:

```
const int huge = 10;
const int tiny = 4;
const int significant = 5;
const int unimporatnt = 10;
short value;
value = huge > tiny ? significant : unimportant;
```

as long as all the operands are `const` variables (pun?).

Now, if I managed to make the explanation clear, you will also know by now that the obstacle preventing `value = "test" == str ? 5 : 10;` from working is that you did not mark the `str` local as `const`. Do that, and it will be allowed.

With the `Equals` call, things are a bit worse. The result of a call to `Equals` is never considered a compile-time constant (and I don't think it is "optimized" away, for example `"same".Equals("same")` will actually call the method at run-time). Same thing would happen with `(10).Equals(4)` or `(10).CompareTo(4) > 0` and so on, so strings are not special in this respect.

---

Most likely you know already that when

```
short value = cond ? 5 : 10;
```

is not allowed because `cond` is not a compile-time constant, you just use the explicit conversion instead, so write:

```
short value = cond ? (short)5 : (short)10;
```

or:

```
short value = (short)(cond ? 5 : 10);
```

Technically, they are not identical, since the first one has no narrowing conversion at run-time (the expressions `(short)5` and `(short)10` are literals of type `short`), while the last one has to convert an `int` to `short` at run-time (which is of course cheaper than incredibly cheap).

---

The other (non-deleted!) answers are correct, this is just bonus information.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that `10 > 4 ? 5 : 10;` is actually converted to a constant at compile time before any type casting is needed. Meaning the compiler realized that the turnary statement can actually be reduced to a constant even before any implicit type casting is required for the compilation. So in other words that expression is the same as:

```
value = 5;
```

In the last two statements, that is not true since you are using a variable to hold the values for you and not a constant. The compiler doesn't check the actual value of the variable to see if it can reduce the expression to a constant. So you actually need the casting.

Comment: Isn't  it the same as value = 5  instead of 10?

Comment: Right. Wrote this in a hurry. Fixed.